Applying UDF on PySpark Dataframe
I am importing pyspark libraries as follows
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

conf = SparkConf().set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation","hive")

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkApp").config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

I have a spark data frame as follows
df_delay.show(5, truncate=False)
+-----------+----------------------+----------------------+
|Call Number|Received DtTm         |Dispatch DtTm         |
+-----------+----------------------+----------------------+
|1030101    |04/12/2000 09:00:29 PM|04/12/2000 09:02:00 PM|
|1030104    |04/12/2000 09:09:02 PM|04/12/2000 09:10:29 PM|
|1030106    |04/12/2000 09:09:44 PM|04/12/2000 09:11:47 PM|
|1030107    |04/12/2000 09:13:47 PM|04/12/2000 09:14:13 PM|
|1030108    |04/12/2000 09:14:43 PM|04/12/2000 09:16:24 PM|
+-----------+----------------------+----------------------+

whose schema is
root
 |-- Call Number: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Received DtTm: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Dispatch DtTm: string (nullable = true)


I want to cast the columns into timestamp and find the difference.
I wrote a UDF that converts the string into Timestamp
convert_to_datetime = F.udf(lambda l: F.unix_timestamp(l,"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").cast(T.TimestampType()), T.TimestampType())

And tried applying it on the dataframe
df_delay.withColumn("DispatchTS",
                convert_to_datetime('Dispatch DtTm')
                ).show(5)

But getting error as follows:
PythonException: 
  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ajink\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9092\3273235857.py", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "C:\software\programming\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 159, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\software\programming\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\functions.py", line 5254, in unix_timestamp
    return _invoke_function("unix_timestamp", _to_java_column(timestamp), format)
  File "C:\software\programming\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\column.py", line 63, in _to_java_column
    jcol = _create_column_from_name(col)
  File "C:\software\programming\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\column.py", line 55, in _create_column_from_name
    sc = get_active_spark_context()
  File "C:\software\programming\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 201, in get_active_spark_context
    raise RuntimeError("SparkContext or SparkSession should be created first.")
RuntimeError: SparkContext or SparkSession should be created first.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong and how to correct. Please help. Greatly appreciate any advice or solution.
Update:
I moved the logic implemented in UDF outside and applied it on data frame directly. Its works.
df_delay.withColumn("DispatchTS",F.unix_timestamp(F.col('Dispatch DtTm'), 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a').cast(T.TimestampType())) \
        .withColumn("ReceivedTS",F.unix_timestamp(F.col('Received DtTm'), 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a').cast(T.TimestampType())) \
        .withColumn('Difference',(F.col('DispatchTS')-F.col('ReceivedTS')).cast(T.IntegerType())/60) \
        .filter(F.col('Difference') > 5) \
        .show()

But I would like to know if there is a way to do the same without repeating the code.

Do you specifically want to do it using UDF? Are you ok with a solution involving built-it functions? Ideally UDFs should be avoided

@RonakJain I wanted to write a DRY code because there are 8 such columns. Also, I am using some built-in functions in the UDF. Not sure if that's the reason for error. After moving the logic out of UDF, I am getting the expected result. Editing the post accordingly.

if you can control data loading, try using inferSchema=True and specify  timestampFormat="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", so you don't have to convert columns one by one in your code.  also, no need to calculate Difference, in your example, just do .filter("int(DispatchTS-ReceivedTS) > 300") or for spark 3.2.0+, use .filter("DispatchTS-ReceivedTS > make_dt_interval(0,0,5)")

Regarding the question

I would like to know if there is a way to do the same without
repeating the code.

A potential solution to accomplish this would be using select and alias, rather than withColumn.


Make a list of the columns you want to convert

dt_columns = ['Received DtTm', 'Dispatch DtTm']


Set-up the statement you want to run on these columns

ts_columns = [F.unix_timestamp(F.col(col_name),'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')\
               .cast(T.TimestampType())\
               .alias(f'{col_name.split(" ")[0]}TS')
              for col_name in dt_columns]

This code snippet is using your same logic but it is set-up for use in a select statement. What it's doing,

taking each column from dt_columns
converting it using .unix_timestamp
running .cast to make it TimestampType
setting the new column name using .alias

The output is a list of pyspark statements.

Select all the columns you want in your output

df_delay.select('Call Number', *dt_columns, *ts_columns).show()




Call Number
Received DtTm
Dispatch DtTm
ReceivedTS
DispatchTS




1030101
04/12/2000 09:00:...
04/12/2000 09:02:...
2000-04-12 21:00:29
2000-04-12 21:02:00


1030104
04/12/2000 09:09:...
04/12/2000 09:10:...
2000-04-12 21:09:02
2000-04-12 21:10:29



The lists cannot be passed to the select statement as a list []. However the elements of the list can be unpacked and passed to the select statement.
Using * before the list variable name provides the unpacked list elements to the select statement
